# How do I import an MP4 video created using the GoPro Hero Camera into the iPad?

Tags: itunes, ipad, video, import

I have recorded some videos using the GoPro Hero Camera set at 960p resolution and 48 frames per second. These videos come out in MP4 format and I an play them on my computer (PC) just fine. However when I try to import them into iTunes and sync with the iPad 4 it says that the video is not in the correct format and can't be played. This is surprising because I was able to do this before on an iPad 2 with no problems. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Apple iPad 4 tech spec:

> MPEG‑4 video up to 2.5 Mbps, 640 by 480 pixels, 30 frames per second

So based on that info, FPS and resolution for mp4 are too high. Use [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr) and convert to H.264 that supports HD on iPad.

Otherwise you can try [Azul](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/azul-media-player-your-password/id406845187?mt=8) media player for iPad that can play almost all formats.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. So i changed my settings to 30 frames per second and it solved the problem. I can now view my go pro vids on ipad. I use the 1080 resolution, by the way, but i dont think youll have a problem using 960. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and just found the answer, set your GoPro to NTSC instead of PAL. Fixed it instantly.

Comment: NTSC is specifically for USA.

Answer (score 0):

Importing the MP4 files to another iPhone app (not the default Videos app but say the VLC player app for iOS). Here's an example of how it works: [How to transfer GoPro videos to iPad or iPhone](http://www.copytrans.net/blog/how-to-transfer-gopro-videos-to-ipad-or-iphone/)